# Locking a metal gate with a deadbolt

Tags: metal, security, gates, deadbolt, welding

I'm having a metal fence custom-made that will have a regular (pedestrian) gate as well as a double gate for vehicles. I'd like to install deadbolts on both gates for better security than other locking methods.

I see several places sell metal boxes that can be welded on with two holes (for a deadbolt and lever) or one hole (for just a deadbolt), so it seems like that will work well. But I'm wondering what to do on the other side opposite the deadbolt. I could just drill a hole through the post, but then there's no strike plate. Or weld a strike plate on and leave a bigger gap to accommodate it? Or do they sell similar metal boxes to weld into the other side?

Comment: On your double gate make sure you have a drop pin to lock 1 side in place or the gate can be pushed in even if locked, I found some specialty double gate locks that were both a drop pin and deadbolt at a local locksmith that was the only place I found this type of mechanism. What material is the single gate it sounds like metal a simple edge can be welded to the metal and a hole drilled no need for a separate strike plate.

Comment: I was looking for something similar a few years ago and I considered these: [bolt on locks](https://www.signetlocks.co.uk/product/select-pro-bolt-on-deadlock/) , [weld on locks](https://www.signetlocks.co.uk/product/select-pro-weld-in-long-throw-keylatch/), [weldable boxes](https://www.keedex.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/KeedexGateboxCatalog.pdf).

Comment: Everything's metal, I was thinking you'd want a strike plate to better match the shape of the deadbolt and door handle/lever bolt below, as neither is a simple circle. And would the deadbolt not be enough to hold the double gate without a drop pin if everything is welded metal on both sides? These are gates with vertical metal posts, so someone could just reach in and retract the drop pin.

Comment: Alternatives also include welding a hasp (abus\abloy make some beefy ones) for use with a padlock. Note that many deadbolts can be easily unscrewed if the intruder can access the other side.

Comment: You could avoid the trouble of a welder by just tapping a few holes and bolting the plates on.

Comment: @UmH most deabolts can only be disassembled when unlocked.

Comment: @Jasen How? If you have access to inside cylinder, can't you unscrew it? Then both cylinders can be removed and the latch can be opened with a screwdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deadbolt doesn't need a strike plate, because the gate is swung with the bolt retracted, and then using the key the bolt is advanced into the hole.

You can use the strike plate if you want and screw or weld it in position over the hole.

For the double gate consider organising the ground pin so that it interferes with the deadlock pin or the other leaf of the gate so that it can't be withdrawn until the gate is unlocked

Answer (score 1):

Though the gate doesn’t need a striker plate, you do need to carefully cut the hole in the shape of a striker plate and at the right place on the rail. That’s tough and I sure would like to hear any tricks there are to it. In addition, ground heaving and other factors often cause the posts to move. Though gate hinges can adjust out most of this, it may be beneficial to make the hole more elongated than you would see on a striker plate. I’m not sure how much bigger to make the hole but it does indicate that it will be more complex than simply drilling a hole.